# is it possible to query workitem custom field in TFS SDK

Tags: tfs

I have few workitems which contain custom field called "Reference ID"
is it possible to query using wiql on this custom field.
Currently I am using the following approach:

//foreach project in TFS

//form the wiql

```
WorkItemCollection workItemCollection = workItemStore.Query(
                    " SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType]," +
                    " [System.State], [System.AssignedTo], [System.Title] " +
                    " FROM WorkItems " +
                    " WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '" + tfsProject.Name +
                    "' ORDER BY [System.WorkItemType], [System.Id]");
```

//run a loop against the result set

//if workitem.Fields["Reference ID"]=required value

//do some tasks on this workitem

this approach is taking quite sometime since there are more than 1000 results.

my question:
is it possible to add custom field also as a filter condition in the above query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You use the field name that's associated with the item.  You can get this using the Process Explorer ([TFS Power Tools](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fvstudio%2Fbb980963.aspx&ei=oldETO_cFIS8lQf70fjKDQ&usg=AFQjCNHTTplc2BhnR8d4-XVfopULd_pyEA&sig2=KLjW-BfREEMDSN121lA4Gw)) and opening the WorkItemType.

Here's an example we use today

```
Select Id from WorkItems where ([xxx.Ticket.OriginalTicketID] = '12345');
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can just hover over the label for the field in the work item editor and you should see a ToolTip with the field name. You can use that field name in your WIQL query.

Comment: True.  I'm a bigger fan of using the internal name, personally-- but of course you're right.  Both will work.

Comment: @Robaticus, You mean "Process Editor" under the tools menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have access to TFS Power Tools or the ability to install it, then you can also use the DisplayForm property of the Work Item Object.

```
myItem = Workitem.GetWorkItem("12345")
myItem.DisplayForm
```

DisplayForm returns an XML containing all the Field Names and Properties. You could look up the XML by label and get the corresponding Control FieldName.

```
myItem.Fields.Item("Custom.FieldName")
```

Comment: There's no such "Item" property within Fields, unfortunately, so this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just add the name of the custom field.